# Framework causing errors in Xcode after adding cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk

I'm trying to implement the IDScan framework and I can get it to build in a brand new blank project. As soon as I add Cocoapods I get these errors.

[image]

I have been trying to get around them all day and I've not been able to get the thing to build...

Anyone got any insight?

Thanks

Comment: For this build of the iOS SDK - you need to add OpenCV 2.4.9, you can download it here - http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-ios/2.4.9/opencv2.framework.zip/download

Answer (score -2):

**You can test on the device. By the error, it can't support simulator.**

Comment: I have been attempting to build it on both sim and phone all day and get the same errors on both

Comment: IDscan's mobile SDK can be tested on both the device and the simulator, a static image will be provided on the simulator screen if the camera is instantiated with the proper controller.